# Bubblewrap HTTP -> Table View; method returns bubblewrap query instead of response data

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

I'm trying out Rubymotion and can't seem to do figure how to accomplish what seems like a simple task.

I've set up a UITableView for a directory of people. I've created a rails back end that returns json.

Person model has a get_people class method defined:

```
def self.get_people
  BubbleWrap::HTTP.get("http://myapp.com/api.json") do |response|
    @people = BW::JSON.parse(response.body.to_str)
    # p @people prints [{"id"=>10, "name"=>"Sam"}, {etc}] to the console
  end
end
```

In the directory_controller I just want to set an instance variable for @data to the array that my endpoint returns such that I can populate the table view.

I am trying to do `@data = Person.get_people` in viewDidLoad, but am getting an error message that indicates the BW response object is being passed instead: `undefined method`count' for #BubbleWrap::HTTP::Query:0x8d04650 ...> (NoMethodError)`

So if I hard code my array into the get_people method after the BW response block everything works fine. But I find that I am also unable to persist an instance variable through the close of the BW respond block.

```
def self.get_people
  BubbleWrap::HTTP.get("http://myapp.com/api.json") do |response|
    @people = BW::JSON.parse(response.body.to_str)
  end
  p @people #prints nil to the console
  # hard coding [{"id"=>10, "name"=>"Sam"}, {etc}] here puts my data in the table view correctly
end
```

What am I missing here? How do I get this data out of bubblewrap's response object and in to a usable form to pass to my controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the BW documentation "BW::HTTP wraps NSURLRequest, NSURLConnection and friends to provide Ruby developers with a more familiar and easier to use API. The API uses **async** calls and blocks to stay as simple as possible."

Due to async nature of the call, in your 2nd snippet you are printing @people before you actually update it. THe right way is to pass the new data to the UI after parsing ended (say for instance @table.reloadData() if @people array is supposed to be displayed in a UITableView).

Here's an example:

```rb
def get_people
    BubbleWrap::HTTP.get("http://myapp.com/api.json") do |response|
        @people  = BW::JSON.parse(response.body.to_str)
        update_result()
    end
end

def update_result()
    p  @people
    # do stuff with the updated content in @people
end
```

Find a more complex use case with a more elaborate explanation at [RubyMotion async programming with BubbleWrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167304/rubymotion-async-programming-with-bubblewrap)

Comment: I am having the same problem and I am not sure I understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd skip BubbleWrap and go for something like this:

```
def self.get_people
  people = []
  json_string = self.get_json_from_http
  json_data = json_string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  e = Pointer.new(:object)
  hash = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json_data, options:0, error: e)
  hash["person"].each do |person| # Assuming each of the people is stored in the JSON as "person"
    people << person
  end
  people # @people is an array of hashes parsed from the JSON
end

def self.get_json_from_http
  url_string = ("http://myapp.com/api.json").stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  url = NSURL.URLWithString(url_string)
  request = NSURLRequest.requestWithURL(url)
  response = nil
  error = nil
  data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response, error: error)
  raise "BOOM!" unless (data.length > 0 && error.nil?)
  json = NSString.alloc.initWithData(data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
end
```